# Install Microsoft Teams for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, microsoft-teams

I want to install microsoft teams for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS so I can join a video conference. Unfortanetly, I am getting a 404 from [the deb download page](https://aka.ms/get-teams). I don't want to install the unofficial client from snap for security concerns. Does anyone have this working?

Comment: The 404 is clearly a website bug, even if they deprecated the older package in preference of a newer one as one of the answers says *(in which case the link, obviously, should lead to the newer package)*. So you need to talk to their support to make sure they are aware of the problem and fix that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as you are not going to be doing any complex screen sharing, I have found the website (teams.microsoft.com) running in Edge is more reliable, uses less memory, and is generally faster than the locally installed clients. I have been doing this for a few years on systems running 20.04 and 22.04 without issues.

What works:

- chat
- file sharing
- audio calls
- video calls (with or without background blurring)
- sharing an entire display (with sound)

What doesn't work:

- sharing a single application window

So long as this is something you can live with then the browser and website may be the way to go.

Comment: Do you use Wayland ? Is the list above (what works) running correctly on Wayland?

Comment: Running in Edge?  Isn't Edge a Windows browser ?

Comment: @Stewart it is [available for Linux and Mac](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download?form=MA13FJ) in addition to Windows. My employer is very Office365-centered now, so having Edge on Ubuntu makes life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has decided to deprecate the native Teams application. It has not seen development in quite a while and is missing quite a lot of newer features. The official solution moving forward is to use the PWA application version of teams. It isn't ideal but is completely usable. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/end-of-the-road-for-teams-linux-desktop-client/m-p/3630968

Comment: yeah, the PWA download page has a link that is broken. i guess i will use edge? :(

Comment: @qciccoretti the PWA only works in Edge, so you'll have to use Edge for that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there's a problem with the distribution of Microsoft Teams for Linux, I've seen more people complaining about this [here on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=teams&searchOn=3). And also saw it on [twitter](https://twitter.com/kdabrowskidev/status/1635973344657911814). It's very likely that as was already pointed out on this thread [discontinuation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/end-of-the-road-for-teams-linux-desktop-client/m-p/3630968) of the "native" package was already carried out, but they forgot to remove the pages that lead to the download.

As others pointed out you can use Teams on the Web Browser.

Comment: thanks, good answer but i don't have enough karma for upvotes. i'll be using edge

Answer (score 0):

As other answers correctly state, Microsoft has discontinued its Linux Teams client, but in its place it has added features to its web-based client that were previously missing.

I am writing this answer to suggest the Teams for Linux app by Ismael Martinez on Flathub which is a community-made wrapper that uses Electron to present the web based client (also known as the PWA client) as if it's its own app.  It's regularly updated and works well for me, including things like minimizing to to tray and having notifications.